# knockout and mouse events issues on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, knockout.js, mouseevent

I have this code:

HTML:

```
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="event: { mouseover: switchStatusEditingMode, mouseout: switchStatusEditingMode }">
                    <span data-bind="visible:statusEditingMode() === 0">New</span>
                    <select data-bind="visible:statusEditingMode() === 1">
                        <option value="0" selected="selected">New</option>
                        <option value="1">Shipped</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

JS:

```
function ViewModel() {
     this.statusEditingMode = ko.observable(0);

     var self = this;
     self.switchStatusEditingMode = function () {
            var newMode = (self.statusEditingMode() + 1) % 2;
           self.statusEditingMode(newMode);
     }
}

window.onload = function(){
     var viewMode = new ViewModel();
     ko.applyBindings(viewMode);
};
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/94d43/1/)

- When you mouse over the text, you will see a select dropdown and when
  mouse out, you will see the text.
- This code works fine on Chrome,
  Firefox, Opera, Safari, but it has difficulty selecting an item from
  the dropdown on IE.
- I'm using IE 10 and with all modes (IE10,IE9,IE8,IE7), it has the same problem.
- I also know the differences between mouseover/mouseenter, mouseout/mouseleave. But with mouseenter and mouseleave, it also has the same problem on IE and works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari.

My question is: how to fix this issue on IE? Thank you.

Comment: In IE9 it seems to be working fine

Comment: @ArunpJohny: I'm using IE10, maybe IE9 works differently than IE9 mode in IE10